# Deleting Duplicate Entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am successfully able to select duplicate queries in phpmyadmin as follow

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ID)
FROM LINKS
GROUP BY URL
HAVING COUNT( ID ) >1
```

Now, I need to delete the same entries which are having duplicate entries, what is the query I need to run for the fetched queries. Just before deleting, I want to make sure, that I am running the correct one. Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont want to add unique index as script developers not recommended this. (this is a directory script bought with a license)

Comment: Nobody forces you to keep that constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it:

https://coderwall.com/p/pypbpw?i=4&p=1&q=author%3Amorteza-ipo&t%5B%5D=morteza-ipo

Here is an example of how to remove duplicate rows in MySQL.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS removeDuplicates;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION removeDuplicates(x int)
    RETURNS TINYINT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE x int;
        SET x = x;
        REPEAT

            DELETE FROM `my-queue` WHERE id IN 
            (
                SELECT id FROM 
                (
                    SELECT id, COUNT( * ) AS c,  `to` ,  `msg` 
                    FROM  `my-queue` 
                    GROUP BY  `to` ,  `msg` 
                    HAVING c >1
                ) as tem1
            );

            SET x = x - 1; 
        UNTIL x < 1 END REPEAT;
        RETURN 1;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And just call it :

```
select removeDuplicates(100);
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi, it did not delete the entire duplicates, it just deleted 1. For example, I had 4 url duplicates of example.com and it deleted only 1 and rest 3 duplicates were present

Comment: @sammry you can test that code with procedure.

Comment: I did, as I said, it still remains. But I ran twice the same query then it helped to remove, thanks, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @sammry I updated the post , check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aecd3/1). This query works too and keeps the rows with the least IDs...

```
DELETE L1
FROM LINKS L1
    JOIN LINKS L2 ON L1.URL = L2.URL
WHERE L1.ID > L2.ID
```